# sublime text + python's anaconda

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I installed package called Anaconda into my Sublime Text 3  
Simple command such as 1+1 doesn't show anything but function print does.

[Simple code like 1+1 doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFdV0.png)

[But python's print function works well.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoYtw.png)

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it may give you correct answers for the script part i.e `print` but for things such as `1+1` you need an interactive console. You can just install anaconda directly in your os from [this link](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) this would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Sublime console is not made an interactive console. When you run the python code it actually runs the file. You can check this by typing `1+1` in a file, saving it in a .py format and then running the file as

```
python -u filename.py
```

which is how sublime executes the code as seen in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ZpuwW-9T54 at 2:36.

You can check the same response to a similar question in this discussion forum as well. https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/running-python-on-sublime-console/18621/2